# How to subtract current row from prior row and so on in power bi

Tags: powerbi

I have one calculated table which has following fields.

```
Year          Revenue
2005          200
2006          300
2007          400
2008          300
```

Above table is generated from following DAX

```
revenue_summary = SUMMARIZE('WA_Retail-SalesMarketing_-ProfitCost',[Year],"Total Revenue",SUM('WA_Retail-SalesMarketing_-ProfitCost'[Revenue]))
```

My desrired table would be

```
Year          Revenue       Differrence
2005          200           0
2006          300           (300-200)= 100
2007          400           (400-300)=100
2008          300           (300-400)=-100
```

How can I achieve this power BI?

Answer (score 1):

```
Difference = 
  var curYear = MyTable[year] 
  var curVal = MyTable[value]
  var oldYear = MyTable[year]-1
  var oldVal = CALCULATE(
    FIRSTNONBLANK(MyTable[value],1),
    FILTER(MyTable, 
    MyTable[year]=oldYear))
  return IF(CONTAINS(MyTable,MyTable[year],oldYear), curVal-oldVal, 0)
```

Results in:

```
Year          Revenue       Differrence
2005          200           0
2006          300           100
2007          400           100
2008          300          -100
```